# Match exact two digits not more using regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x, date

Am trying to get date sting from filename using regular expression in a python script. Here is my date sting

> '2012-09-25 ag.pdf'

To get date string from this filename am using this regex `r'\d{4}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}'` and it working fine

but some filenames also contains two digit year and for those am trying another regex `r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`

`'2012-09-25 ag.pdf'` also matches with second regex (`r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`) pattern that causing issue with my script

How can i use regex in python to match exact two digits not more than that

Comment: probably just `r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'` or use `match` on the basename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have at least 3 options here:

*First option*: match the 4-digit year date first, and it matches, don't try to match the 2-digit year date.

*Second option*: modify your 2-digit year option to be more restrictive:

```
r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
```

*Third option*: use `match` on the basename, not `search`. `match` tries to match from the start. If it finds 4 digits it will be a no-match.

Answer (score 2):

You can create one regex for both cases:

```
^\d{2,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nZwZ58/4/

The good think about this first version is that is simpler and readable the bad thing is that will match a date with 3 digit.

The next one is **more especific but more verbose**.

```
^\d\d(\d\d)?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nZwZ58/3/

Comment: Will this not result in matches for filenames with 3 digit years? Which would probably be errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right @PyPingu. I  added a second option more verbose but more accurate. Thanks you your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your date will always be at the start of the filename you could anchor your regex like so:

`r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`

More docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

EDIT:
Could also use an `or` match:

`r'^(\d{2}|\d{4})-\d{2}-\d{2}'`

Answer (score 0):

If Your filenames are always like this, you can prepend your regexp with `^` to match only on the beginning.